# Is there std::memset equivalent for std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, memset, stdarray

Is there a memset equivalent for `std::array`? I think `memset` is supposed to perform  better when initializing an array to zero than looping over the array. I searched one for `std::array` but could not find anything online.

Comment: The point is that you won't find `memset` because it won't work for any type `T` that is non-POD.  This is not only the case for `std::array<T, n>`, but for any container based on a generic `T` type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It would be possible to conditionally enable a `memset` method based on `std::is_pod<T>::value`, though… (I should point out that `is_pod` is scheduled for deprecation in C++20.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the array's  [`fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) method, that is what its purpose is.

If you fill it with `0` (for integers, for instance), then the compiler may optimize it if it can (often does, you can look at the generated code).

Comment: And if in pre-modern C++ which doesn't have `std::array` much less `std::array::fill` you can fill anything that you've got two iterators to with `std::fill` from `<algorithms>` and a good implementation will have specializations for different kinds of iterators and value types so it can be very efficient. (And it'll work with `std::array` too.)

Comment: std::fill will be optimized by being replaced with a memset(). The decision is made at compile time by using the type_traits.